# Angular Material md-icon error No provider for Http

Tags: angular, angular-material

When using `<md-icon>` I get this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!

So I added `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to my component and it solved it. So my question... Why do I need to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to my component to get `<md-icon>` to work even though I'm not using `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in my app otherwise?!

Here's my working component. Removing `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from the providers array throws the above error.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { MdIcon, MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'foo-app',
  template: `<md-icon>face</md-icon>`,
  directives: [ MdIcon ],
  providers: [MdIconRegistry, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class FooAppComponent {
  title = 'Material 2 Foo App';
}
```

One other note, this line will display the icon with no Http error and no need for `HTTP_PROVIDERS`:

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

Comment: Does a child of this component use `@angular/http`?  If so, HTTP_PROVIDERS is required.  It may be required even if it's imported and not used.

Comment: This is the base App component - no other components. Also, when I remove `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from provider array, I also remove the import, so that's not the issue. This is a strange one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the source code a bit for angular2-material, md-icon depends on angular2's `Http` which is why you're seeing the need for HTTP_PROVIDERS.

heres a link to the source: 
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/components/icon/icon.ts

in /src/components/icon/icon.ts, the class requires `MdIconRegistry` with `MdIcon` having the constructor:

```
constructor(
  private _element: ElementRef,
  private _renderer: Renderer,
  private _mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry) { }
```

and `MdIconRegistry` requires `Http` with `MdIconRegistry` having the constructor:

```
  constructor(private _http: Http) {}
```

I guess Http is used to perhaps get icons from a url? So if you dig a few levels down into the source code, you can find Http in there.

Comment: There is a call to `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in the index page, so perhaps `HTTP_PROVIDERS` is needed to call that url. :/

Answer (score 4):

**Angular 7**

For *me* the solution to this error was to add `MatIconRegistry` to providers on my APP module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [
   ..,MatIconModule,
    HttpClientModule,
   ..
  ],
  providers:[  MatIconRegistry ],
  exports: [..]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

Comment: Adding MatIconRegistry in the list of providers helped fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/components/icon/icon-registry.ts) reveals that MdIcon uses MdIconRegistry which uses Http to load the icon.  This is also mentioned in a [comment for MdIcon.](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/components/icon/icon.ts)

It still seems strange that that library is not self contained, but for now that seems to be the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Using angular 2.1.0 and angular material 2.0.0-alpha.10 do the following:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
```